# Does NestJS clean up unreachable durable providers?

Tags: nestjs

If I have a DI subtree created with providers marked with `scope.REQUEST` and `durable: true`, will Node garbage collect these subtrees if they become unreachable? Or does Nest hold onto a reference to them?

If they can't be garbage collected, is there a way to trigger Nest to cleanup a particular subtree based on it's contextId?

I have looked through the Injection Scopes and ModuleRef docs and didn't find any information about this.
I have tried creating many unreachable DI subtrees while monitoring my Nest app's memory usage, and found that the memory usage did not significantly change.
I was also unable to find a way to list the DI subtrees currently stored in Nest or any documentation.

Comment: there's no way to find out if that provider will be used or not, right? that's up to the context id strategy, I guess

Comment: If I understand what you're saying (that only the contextId strategy implementation can determine which providers will be used), I think that's correct. But I'm not sure if Nest also stores references to all DI subtrees itself somewhere, preventing them from being garbage collected.

Comment: I believe that they are weak references. You could try to use [`FinalizationRegistry`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry) to find that out